# Recursion: NameError: name 'maxSubArray' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Question]

The error message says: Line 10: NameError: name 'maxSubArray' is not defined

Is there anything wrong when I do the recursion in python?

Comment: Post the actual code, not an image.

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `self.MaxSubArray`